# Do I need virtualization to build in React Native and Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, virtualization

I've been developing in Win 10 Home for years, and I have a React-Native project with Expo.  Do I need virtualization for this as Win 10 Home doesn't provide for Virtualization?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run it on a virtual emulator on your computer, then yeah you need to enable virtualization. If Windows 10 Home doesn't support that, you may be out of luck... However, you should be able to select the Tunnel option within Expo and use the Expo app on your actual phone to scan the barcode and download the source code to run the app. Note this still supports hot reloading.

Comment: @markanthony no worries, I'm trying to get to 50 rep so I can comment on others' posts if you wouldn't mind accepting or upvoting the answer. :)

Comment: Upvoted...but apparently because I'm a noob.."Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: No worries, but since it's your question you should be able to hit the check mark, assuming you want to accept it. :) @markanthony

Comment: Done....thanks again.  Expo is working like a charm.